# How do i access a Variant from a struct which is in a vector

Tags: rust

```
enum StudentNames {
    Vlad, 
    Andrei,
    Dragos,
}

struct Student {
    student_name: StudentNames,
    locker: Option<i32>,
}


fn main() {
    let students = vec![
        Student {
            student_name: StudentNames::Vlad,
            locker: Some(1),
        },
        Student {
            student_name: StudentNames::Andrei,
            locker: Some(2),
        },
        Student {
            student_name: StudentNames::Dragos,
            locker: None,
        },   
    ];
    for student in students {
        
    }
   
}
```

I am trying to return the student name by matching the locker variant for each student. Using a match against `Some`/`None` didn't work, when referencing by `students.Student::locker`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably include the specific `match` code you used to attempt to get the information you wanted. Right now that block is empty - you define `students` but you're not showing us what you're trying in the `for student in students` block.

Comment: I'm not sure what `students.Student::locker` is supposed to mean, but have you tried just matching on `student.locker`?

Comment: You should add the `match` in your snippet, it would be easier to help you